# Link for mute toggle using JW Player flash with fallback to HTML5 video not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwplayer

EDIT: Wow, solved it by placing the 'file' and 'flashplayer' configs first in the configuration section. I guess those two parameters have to be first in the configuration section.

So this works (You cant load the file from longtailvideo.com like this because of cross domain stuff, just use your own local file to test)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="vs" style="width:300px;height:250px;"></div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="jwplayer().setMute();">Toggle the audio</a>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("vs").setup({
file: "http://content.longtailvideo.com/videos/flvplayer.flv",
flashplayer: "player.swf",
autostart:true,
controlbar: "none",
icons: "false",
repeat:"always",
stretching:"exactfit",
width:300,
height:250,
mute:"true"
});
</script>
```

Can't get the mute toggle working. According to Longtail's documentation (http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/16022/controlling-the-player-using-javascript) all I have to do is make a link with an onclick. Doesnt work. I even tried a .click with JQuery to no avail. Using MP4 files so the code falls back from flash to HTML5 video.

This doesnt work either with JQuery included in the page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#mutetoggle').click(function(){
jwplayer().setMute();
});
});
</script>
```

JW Player with JW javascript for embed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="vs" style="width:300px;height:250px;"></div>
<a href="#" id="mutetoggle" onclick="jwplayer().setMute();">Toggle the audio</a>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("vs").setup({
autostart:true,
controlbar: "none",
icons: "false",
repeat:"always",
stretching:"exactfit",
file: "http://content.longtailvideo.com/videos/flvplayer.flv",
flashplayer: "player.swf",
volume:50,
width:300,
height:250,
mute:"true"
});
</script>
```

Comment: How about jwplayer("vs").setMute();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the file and flashplayer parameters have to be first in the configuration section.
Go figure.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="vs" style="width:300px;height:250px;"></div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="jwplayer().setMute();">Toggle the audio</a>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("vs").setup({
file: "http://content.longtailvideo.com/videos/flvplayer.flv",
flashplayer: "player.swf",
autostart:true,
controlbar: "none",
icons: "false",
repeat:"always",
stretching:"exactfit",
width:300,
height:250,
mute:"true"
});
</script>
```